# How to fix a broken Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I open an existing Maven project, the IDE shows only those files on the root directory, but not any directories in the project. After a while, the IDE will show the project as what it is in the file structure, but not the directory types such as source code, test when I reopen the project. I reinstall the community edition, but the problem still resists. I have experienced the same issue for a few Java projects lately.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1, Please ask another teammate to check if that project really works. Sometimes the application structure already broken, then it is not your local problem.

2, There is a .idea folder in the application, delete it. Or simply, you git clone a new place Important: Please notice if you have edited / created some new files in the original directory, otherwise you would lost them if you delete the application.

3, Open intellij, and File -> Invalite caches

Personally, the second point is recommendated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to click on `Reload All Maven Projects` in Maven tool window:

[image]

If it doesn't help you can try to perform the following actions:

- Close the project with `File | Close Project`.
- Close the IDE.
- Open your project in OS file manager and remove all .iml files and the .idea directory.
- [Reimport](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start) the project.

If the problem remains [contact](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) JetBrains support and attach a compressed [log folder](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) along with the project structure tree.